# how to show popup Activity or Dialog when phone is locked?

Tags: android

I am trying to show a activity or a dialog when the phone is locked.
I have tried using a WakeLock but it did not work and I can only see the activity once my phone is unlocked?

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [KeyGuardManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html) to unlock the device automatically and then acquire your Wake Lock.

```
    KeyguardManager kgm = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    boolean isKeyguardUp = kgm.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
    KeyguardLock kgl = kgm.newKeyguardLock("Your Activity/Service name");

    if(isKeyguardUp){
    kgl.disableKeyguard();
    isKeyguardUp = false;
    }

    wl.acquire(); //use your wake lock once keyguard is down.
```

Answer (score 10):

To show activity without dismissing the keyguard try this:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
setContentView();
```

Comment: Thanks I have found this 2, It's the better solution but only if you use android 2.0 +

Comment: pretty hacky, but it does what it should!

Answer (score 2):

To show a popup on top of a lock screen try this, from my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27382507/1129332):

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        alertDialog.show();
```

To show activity on top of a lock screen, or basically remove the lock screen when activity is starts, try this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
     ...
}
```

Both of those options require api 5+