# How do I get android lockscreen package name

Tags: android, package, lockscreen

Is there a way to get the android lockscreen package name?

I want to show alert on the lockscreen using `AlertDialog.Builder`. So I need to know when the lockscreen is active and what it's package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a native solution. After you build the Alert dialog and before showing it, apply this:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        alertDialog.show();
```

This will show the dialog on top of the lock screen.

Comment: @llya_Gazman it si not working, is there any permission required.

Comment: @FaisalAhsan Nop, no permissions. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED

Answer (score 2):

You can detect if the lockscreen is shown with:

```
((KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE)).inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
```

And you can get the current top activity with:

```
(ActivityManager) getSystemService(Service.ACTIVITY_SERVICE).getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity;
```

This will usually be the lockscreen activity, but it is possible that for example the phone app is shown while the lockscreen is active: in this case it will be the phone activity.

You will need the android.permission.GET_TASKS permission for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Really a Simple solution.

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

if( km.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
               //it is locked

                  }
```