# Start intent when user is switching off the android phone

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a way to trigger an intent when user is switching off his/her android phone ?

Comment: why do not user Services ?

Comment: Can you please explain what u wan to do? I think you can only use background service like @Tigran said.

Comment: @Shawn and Tigran i want to stop the switching off 
if my application is downloading something or doing some critical processing.
Or at-least prompt a user with a warning.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3814239/2654254 try something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190184/2654254 ???

You can use BroadcastReceiver, It's explain well in this answer.

Sorry, my english is poor :)