# Android show alert in screen lock

Tags: android, screen-lock

I try to show alert when screen is locked
I googled about screen locked but i do not know how i can check when screen is locked.
I found one  post but i do not know how this method working 
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813131/how-to-show-popup-activity-or-dialog-when-phone-is-locked)

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

But I don't know  how to show alert when screen is locked, If anyone knows solution please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You might just use a toast:

```
Toast.makeText(appcontext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Or if you really need a popup, then why not just remove this flag temporarily from your screen while the popup is displayed?

Comment: msg is the message what you wish to display (a String)